# MySQL copying over auto increment primary IDs

Tags: mysql

I have an old database where I want to copy the entire row into a new table, but preserve the original id column (which is a primary/autoincrement field)

It seems to insert one row and then stop saying:

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Am I missing some constraint issue/autoincrement not liking me explicitly choose the id #? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide sample data, the data already in the new table, and the statements you are using to copy the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying a row with ID of 2 when there is already a row in the table with an ID of 2. You can choose your own ID numbers as long as they're unique.